# How to accept stream of data coming from a file in list python

Tags: python, stream, stdout, stdin

I am supposed to `append` all the integer values from `STDIN` in python.

For example:

```
5
6
0
4
2
4
1
0
0
4
```

Suppose the below is the integers coming from stdin, how can append these values in a `list`?

My code:

```
result = []

try:
    while raw_input():
        a = raw_input()
        result.append(int(a))
except EOFError:
    pass

print result
```

Could anyone help me? Thank you

> Result is only printing [6, 4, 4, 0, 4]

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: You are calling `raw_input` twice per loop

Comment: @walpen if you write your answer,  I will upvote and accept it. You're correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have called `raw_input()` twice.

```
while raw_input(): # this consumes a line, checks it, but does not do anything with the results
    a = raw_input()
    result.append(int(a))
```

As a general note about python. Stream like objects, including files opened for reading, stdin and `StringIO` among others, have an iterator that iterates over there lines. So your program can be reduced to the pythonic.

```
import sys
result = [int(line) for line in sys.stdin]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are consuming every second raw_input in the while line, change this to test that 'a' is non-null.  For example:

```
result = []

try:
    a = raw_input()
    while a:
        result.append(int(a))
        a = raw_input()
except EOFError:
    pass
```

print result

Answer (score 0):

Okay my issue is resolved using `fileinput` module

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the raw_input() in the while loop to a variable ('a' in your case) should fix the issue.

```
result = []


a = raw_input("Enter integer pls:\n> ")
try:
    while a is not '':
        result.append(int(a))
        a = raw_input("Enter another integer pls:\n> ")
except ValueError:
    pass

print result
```